# http request body format and how to accept with php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm struggling with an integration with a web service. A bit new to this, so I'm sure it's obvious, but I'm missing the how-to part.

I know how to handle data posted via AJAX to my PHP using something like this: `$obj = $_POST['myData'];`

I can handle this data just fine after that whether it be adding to a database or whatever.

Now I have a third party website that allows me to send an HTTP request. I need to supply the URL to the endpoint (which I'm assuming is the PHP file on my server I want to use to process the data).It's a POST request and I can create a body (in JSON format to send). I can construct this JSON with the right format and fields I need. Like this:

```
{
"val1":"12.121",
"val2":"232.4"
}
```

Here's the first question...what do I use in place of `myData` in this line: `$obj = $_POST['myData'];`? Do I need to somehow include the `myData` part in my JSON body that I'm sending?

Once I have the data, I can parse it using `json_decode` and go from there.

Final question...what's the best way to test this? When I'm using AJAX, I can just do a `var_dump` for different variables and see what's working. How do I do something similar if data is being sent from a third party to my server?

Thanks!

EDIT: seeing the supposed duplicate post, but this situation is different in that I don't control the web service, so I can't really control how the code works on that end. All I can do is type in the body of the request that I can send in a sort of WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: you're SENDING a post to this other service? or RECEIVING a post from them?

Comment: @MarcB I'm receiving with my PHP from this web service, but I can also set the format of the body that is sent from the web service